# LoginUsingId() not working within midleware jwt.auth, Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel

This has been driving me crazy for 2 hours can't seem to fix it if I put my routes inside the jwt.auth midleware. I want to login as another user while I am already logged in as admin from my admin dashboard using the LoginUsingId() function in Laravel, and it works all good if I dont pass the token as parameter, but I have to protect my api using the jwt token so I cant remove the midleware jwt.auth.. Is there anyway that I can make it work even the routes are inside the midleware jwt.auth?

Working example:

```
//Login as other User
Route::post('users/loginas/{userId}', ['as' => 'login_as', 'uses' => 'UserController@loginAs']);
Route::get('classes/{class_id}/market_feeds', ['as' => 'show_market_feeds', 'uses' => 'MarketFeedController@index']);
Route::group(['middleware' => 'jwt.auth'], function () {

})
```

Not working:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'jwt.auth'], function () {
//Login as other User
Route::post('users/loginas/{userId}', ['as' => 'login_as', 'uses' => 'UserController@loginAs']);
Route::get('classes/{class_id}/market_feeds', ['as' => 'show_market_feeds', 'uses' => 'MarketFeedController@index']);
})
```

My Controller for switching user looks like:

```
public function loginAs($userId)
{
    Auth::logout();
    Auth::loginUsingId($userId, true);
    return response()->json(['logged' => Auth::check(), 'user' => Auth::user()->username, 'id' => Auth::user()->id]);
}
```

Works good and I can see the user details... but when I try to make another call like calling this function:

```
public function displaySomethingElse($classId)
{
    return response(array('username'=>Auth::user()->username,'id' => Auth::user()->id));
}
```

It returns the admin user, not the specific user I want...

I hope I was enough clear.

Comment: That is very very much expected behavior as jwt auth's login by id is done based on the id present in the token. So, the `id` in token, is always your "admin's" `id`.

Comment: One approach I can think of is to decode the token on front-end, replace with other users id, and then encode again using the same algorithm which jwt.auth uses, and pass it as `Bearer` Authorization. (Haven't tried this before though, it'll be good to know if it works)

Comment: So, what would you suggest me to do? What would be the best solution to solve this?

Comment: thnx, I will try if that  works...

Comment: it should work, if you dont change any other values apart from `sub` key. This might be helpful https://github.com/auth0/jwt-decode

Comment: @VishalSh do you mean changing payload part of jwt? wouldnt that change the signature of the token, so that wont be authorised from my server anymore? I am not that good understanding the token working.. but just wanted to ask before I try to change all these things...

Comment: yeah only the `sub` part of the `payload` section. Give it a try, no harm. I don't think signature will be changed. If it doesn't work, we can always raise a ticket on jwt auth git and let the maker think for a solution on this.

Comment: umm, I think it will not work.

Comment: Let me write an answer for this. I think that approach will make more sense

Comment: btw I tried to modify the payload and didnt work. when I make a request after I modify the payload I get "error": "token_invalid"..

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that. I tried that approach just now and saw that if i change the payload signature changes as well. Tried changing the payloads here:: http://jwt.io/ and saw that signature is changing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach that you can follow is to generate the token based on user object and return that. And, use the returned token for the next calls.

The library which you are using has an option of [generating tokens based on user object](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/wiki/Creating-Tokens#creating-a-token-based-on-a-user-object)

You can pass the `id` or any other identifier of the user that you want to login as. Remember, that this call is as `admin`. Receive the response token genrated from user object and use this token for your next calls. That makes you logged in as the user you want to login as.

Please feel free to comment, if you did not understand what I am trying to say.